# Apply changes from git history to a different software version

Tags: git, revision-history

Let's say I had downloaded a `1.0.10` version of Kanboard (kanboard.net), put it in my git repository and then made some changes to it to customize it the way I wanted. But after that there was a newer `1.0.11` version of the Kanboard released. Now I wonder if it's possible to apply all the changes (commits?) I made to a new vanilla copy of the `1.0.11` version.

I'm completely new to git so I don't really know where to even look. Just tell me if something like this is even possible and if so just point me in the right direction, I can learn the rest on my own.

Comment: If you just have a vanilla 1.0.11 this is hard because you have no shared baseline.  One option would be to take a branch in your original 1.0.10 repository from the vanilla code (ie at the baseline bfore you made any changes) and place the 1.0.11 code into it and commit.  You then have a common ancestor for 1.0.11 and 1.0.10.yours.  From there you can merge your branch onto this branch in the normal way.  Once that is done you have 1.0.11 + your stuff which you can then always copy over then changed files onto a vanilla 1.0.11 and commit

Answer (score 0):

This sort of things is easiest if you have your changes in a separate branch.  If this is the case, you can use the `git rebase` operation to move your changes from one version to another.  That is, assume that you start with the repository at version `1.0.10`, and you create a branch to work on some bugfixes/features:

```
$ git status
On branch master
[...]
$ git checkout -b myfeature
```

And now you make some changes.  At some point later, version `1.0.11` of the upstream code is available, so you first update your repository:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
```

Now you can `rebase` your changes on top of the updated `master` branch:

```
$ git checkout myfeature
$ git rebase master
```

This would replay the changes in your `myfeature` branch on top of the updated `master` branch.  It's possible at this point that you will need to resolve some merge conflicts, but [there is documentation on how to handle this](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts-after-a-git-rebase/).

A key part of this workflow is that you keep your local work separate from the upstream work.